# Standardized way of collecting logging information?

Tags: .net, logging

We have dozens of large server-side applications scattered around the enterprise - all with different ways of logging information and reporting errors.

I am trying to build a dashboard (over time) that shows the health of all the apps at a glance as well as providing a look at any problems the apps might be having.  Obviously, it would be nice to standardize on a single way to log info.

Obviously, I could roll my own, but I was wondering whether a standard already exists that addresses these challenges.  Perhaps, something that allows a client application to connect/query server-side apps (or read their log files) without affecting performance too much and fetch state info.

P.S.  All apps are mix of C# in .NET 2/3.5/4.  Some apps use Log4Net, others roll their own.

Answer (score 2):

Use the event log to report errors. There are dozens of applications that can monitor it.

Use SNMP to monitor the health of the applications.

Logging is only for diagnostics/debugging imho.

Comment: Event Viewer is fine for error reporting.  I am more interested retrieving logging information in a reasonable standardized manner.

Comment: AFAIK there is no standard. Just specify your own log format and make sure that all follows it (independent of logging framework)